# Django and Apache: Start addional thread for MQTT Client

Tags: python, django, apache

I want to start an apache-server with an additional mqtt-client. I am using Django and Apache in production. To start my mqqt client, I edited the `wsgi.py` this is working perfectly, if I am using the development server (`python3 manage.py runserver`). But its not working in production. Can any help or has an idea how to get this working in production with apache?

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
import threading
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('mqtt')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "iot.settings")


from iot.settings import MQTT_CONNECTION, MQTT_BROKER
if MQTT_CONNECTION:
    logger.debug('Connecting to Broker...')
    try:
        from utils_mqtt_client.mqtt_client import run_client
        run_client()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.debug('Could not conntect to MQTT Broker:\n\t {}'.format(e))
else:
    logger.debug('Starting without MQTT connection')


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**mqqt-client:**

```
import json
import threading
import logging
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

from device.models import Device
from value.models import Value

from iot.settings import MQTT_BROKER

logger = logging.getLogger('mqtt')

topics = ['config']
CLIENT = mqtt.Client('webserver')

# [...]

def run_client():
    devices = Device.objects.all()

    CLIENT.on_connect = on_connect
    CLIENT.on_message = on_message

    for device in devices:
        subscribe(CLIENT, device)

    CLIENT.connect(MQTT_BROKER)

    CLIENT.loop_start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it working with modifying my wsgi.py like this:

```
import os
import time
import threading
import logging

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "iot.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()

logger = logging.getLogger('mqtt')
from iot.settings import MQTT_CONNECTION, MQTT_BROKER
if MQTT_CONNECTION:
    logger.debug('Connecting to Broker...')  
    from utils_mqtt_client.mqtt_client import run_client
    run_client()
else:
    logger.debug('Starting without MQTT connection')
```